# Why does adding CDay() to DatetimeIndex include a weekend?

Tags: python, pandas, datetimeoffset, datetimeindex

I am on pandas version 1.1.3.

Suppose I have the following index

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.tseries.offsets import CDay

idx = pd.bdate_range("2010-02-03","2010-02-12") + pd.Timedelta('22H')
```

If I then add:

```
shifted_idx = idx + 0*CDay(offset=pd.Timedelta('4H'))
```

I would expect the timestamp in `idx` of `2010-05-05 22:00` to move to `2010-05-08 02:00` since `CDay()` has `weekmask = ‘Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri’` by default.

However, we see in `shifted_idx` a timestamp `2010-02-06 02:00:00` which is on a Saturday and violates the weekmask?

Comment: @mhc56 since the bounty expires tomorrow, it would be awesome if you could take a look at my answer and give your feedback ;).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `offset` parameter is applied *after* the day shift is applied, that's why you are getting these results.

You can see that by taking a look at [the source code of the `apply` method](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/4c8d66ecfe2b13607afd254443979b1ff842b6c1/pandas/_libs/tslibs/offsets.pyx#L3222) of the `CustomBusinessDay` class. Note that `CDay` is just an alias of `CustomBusinessDay`.

Not sure if this counts as a bug, because you can argue that this is the intended behavior. I couldn't find any documentation to support nor oppose this.

For now, you can work around this by manually applying the offset first, then applying the mask. Something like this:

```
idx_hours_offset = idx + pd.Timedelta('4H')                                          

shifted_idx = idx_hours_offset + 0*CDay()
```

Comment: Ah okay, this explains it then. Nice to know. I guess the documentation should be a bit more verbose about this

Answer (score -1):

By typing `shifted_idx = idx + 0*CDay(offset=pd.Timedelta('4H'))` you just add 4h to the previous timestamp, the CDay thingy doesn't work there.

It's much simpler to do a normal `pd.date_range` and add the four hours to that range and finally slice the dataframe using the following code:

```
    import pandas as pd
    idx = pd.date_range("2010-02-03","2010-02-12") + pd.Timedelta('22H')
    shifted_idx = idx + pd.Timedelta('4H')
    shifted_idx = shifted_idx[shifted_idx.dayofweek < 5]
```

Comment: This method won't work if I want to include a custom calendar, which is why `CDay` is appealing